# Proxy configuration issues with jvisualvm

Tags: java, proxy, jvisualvm

I have tried the jvisualvm.exe in my JDK (1.6.0_15-b03) to reload the plugin catalog, by following

Tools > Plugins > Updates > Reload Catalog

However; no matter what proxy configuration I try (I also tried to test it on another JVM 1.6 update 23) and does not seem to to work. I get the following errors irrespective of my proxy setup.

> Unable to connect to the Java VisualVM Plugins Center because of
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Here is the error window that comes up [please see attached image][image: certificate error]

Is this a known problem or some certification issue? I have never created a trust store on my machine, could this be a problem?

Comment: you need to find a option not to check validity of the certificate

Answer (score 26):

The VisualVM was migrated to Github so the plugins center is now 
[Here](https://visualvm.github.io/pluginscenters.html)

but to make it short what you need to do is
open **VisualVM**
open **Tools -> Plugins -> Settings**
on the right column ("**Java VisualVM Plugins Center**") click **Edit**
replace whatever you have there with : https://visualvm.github.io/uc/8u131/updates.xml.gz

Comment: worked like charm, thanks

Answer (score 3):

In here you can download plugins manually: http://visualvm.java.net/pluginscenters.html

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. In my research I did find this. However; I think the issue is that the site https://visualvm.dev.java.net/uc/6u14/updates.xml.gz does not have a SSL certificate(I tried to see the webpage in firefox.). Is it possible to ask java not to bother for certificates for a particular site?

Comment: @Ayusman, if you got the message above it means that Proxy is configured okay. And the app recieves a certificate (it might be fake certificate) or valid one. In either case the app cannot check its validity. Now you have two options to find a way to omit certificate check in the app or add fingerprints of that certificate manually in the app.

Comment: is there a way I can add this exception to my JDK keystore? The website https://visualvm.dev.java.net/uc/6u20/updates.xml.gz does not provide a certificate that I can download and add to my keystore. I must agree that my understanding of java trust store is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is to download the plugins manually and then install it on JVisualVM.

Here are the steps :

1. Start with picking up a version of the plugin from : https://visualvm.github.io/pluginscenters.html
2. And then download the particular plugin (the file's extension would be "*.nbm*") that you want to install.
3. Then, in JVisualVM, go to **Tools > Plugin > Downloaded** ; then click "**Add Plugins**" and select the previously downloaded file.
4. Once, it shows up in the "**Downloaded**" plugins tab, then click "**Install**"

Hope this helps...